# How can you make Constraint Layout resist expansion to cover other views

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a constraint layout, and inside it I have a header view and a footer view

Those are anchors that between them have an `EditText` a `RecyclerView` and a `Button` that are chained together.

The layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/app_padding">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        style="@style/app_text.large"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/app_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Hello Header" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        style="@style/app_text.large"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/app_padding"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="Hello footer" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This looks as I want it to, a list with multiple items that is always centered on the screen.

The problem is that when the list is populated with too many items, it starts to expand upwards and covers the header.

To setting the list's `layout_height` to `0dp` solves the problem , but then the list always takes up most of the screen (even with too few items) and the `Button` is always stuck above the footer and the `EditText` is always stuck below the header.

Is there a way to make the `RecyclerView` have `wrap_content` as its layout height but be constrained in some way to never become so big as to cover the header?

I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve setting a max height because this is supposed to run on multiple screen dimensions

Comment: You can set guidelines to limit the area between which you would want the recycler view to exists. You can even set the guidelines with percentages. https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html

Comment: yeah I know about those but they have the same problem, when I wrap_content they do not work, basically I'm just replacing anchors from the header and footer view to a guideline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` attribute set on your `RecyclerView`. This allows to use `wrap_content` on the `view`'s height yet keep enforcing the constraints to limit the resulting height.

Comment: this looks promising, doesn't seem to work well on the designer, but that doesn't say much I'll try it on my normal project when I have some time, thank you

Comment: I have tested it and indeed this does work, unfortunatelly it seems that when I use it in a recyclerview within another recyclerview's viewholder this causes some graphical problems, but I'll figure it out, thanks for the answer